# How can I save the downloaded and converted audios to a specific folder

Tags: python, web-scraping, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download Videos from a specific playlist and converting it to a m4a file for further downloading. The process works perfectly but the files are being saved in the same folder where my Phyton script is located. I choose a specific Output Folder but the files don't appear there.
Any ways to save the files in the desired folder?

An error message reads as follows: `"input.mp4: No such file or directory"`
In my Code block, I censored the playlist link and the user name on the path. Just imagine a working playlist link instead. Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import subprocess
```

#### Replace `<PLAYLIST_URL>` with the URL of the YouTube playlist

`playlist_url = "PLAYLISTLINK"`

#### Set the output directory for the downloaded files

`output_dir = "/Users/USER/Documents/VideoBot/Output"`

#### Use `youtube-dl` to download the latest video in the playlist

`subprocess.run(["youtube-dl", "-f", "bestaudio[ext=m4a]", "--playlist-start", "1", "--playlist-end", "1", playlist_url])`

#### Extract the audio from the downloaded video using `ffmpeg`

`subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", "input.mp4", "-vn", "-acodec", "copy", "output.m4a"])`

#### Move the extracted audio file to the output directory

`os.rename("output.m4a", os.path.join(output_dir, "output.m4a"))`

Comment: You need to create a directory beforehand. If you haven't created a directory beforehand you can have this error.

Comment: Do you mean before running the script or before creating the script?

Comment: Before running the script.

Comment: I copied the path and pasted it before running it. It still let the files download in the other folder and shows the given error message

Comment: Use the relative path instead of absolute path, for instance if you are in directory X and you want to have the videos at the directory names output inside the directory X you can use '/output'. But if you are going to use absolute path then you need to get that path via os module

Comment: I get the following error message: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.m4a' -> '/Users/user1/Documents/VideoBot/Output/output.m4a'